# Generic creation of Model / DB entry with Eloquent / Laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to build a very generic function that receives a model name, and id and an array of values to update an existing model or create a new model, when the id value is empty or cannot be found (in my case)

The problem I'm having is that I cannot find the right way to generic create the new Model like I would usually do: `$mymodel = new Mymodel();`

Here is the relevant part of the function. It is not working and I dug already into the code in the `Illuminate\Database` folder

```
// lets get the model and then we update and save
$model = DB::table($request->input("model")."s")->where('id',$request->input("id"))->first();

if(!$model){
   $model = DB::table($request->input("model")."s")->new();
}

 // This part is not tested yet, but this part should set all the 
 // values from an Array of JSON objects, I will get that part to work
 foreach(json_decode($request->input("values")) as $value){
     $model->attributes[$value->name] = $value->value;
 }
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish this in the easiest way? I don't really want to register all Models I have in a seperate function and create it there. If possible I want to keep it super-generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @joelrosenthal 's answer, here is the complete working code, I hope that will help someone: I have my Models in subfolders.

```
$modelClass = "\App\\".ucwords($request->input("model"));
if(!class_exists($modelClass)){
    $modelClass = "\App\\WFEModels\\".ucwords($request->input("model"));
}
// lets get the model and then we update and save
$model = $modelClass::where('id', $request->input("id"))->first();
// create new Instance if not found
if(!$model){
  $model = new $modelClass();
}
// fill values
foreach($request->input("values") as $value){
    $model[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
}
// save model
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something along the lines of but make sure to validate and sanitize your user input.

```
$modelClass = "App\\{$request->input('model')}";
$model = new $modelClass;
```

Comment: Although this is syntactically not 100% correct, it inspired my solution, which I will post in a separate answer. Thanks and up-vote for you!